# How to limit click area to text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The first column is set to `display: table` and only the text is clickable. That's exactly how it's supposed be.

The second column however is (and has to be, I think...) set to `display: none` and when I have different lengths of text (click CCC to see the best example) it creates a block and the whole width is clickable.

I think the background colors make the issue very clear.

How do I fix this?

Ideally I'd be looking for a CSS fix. However, if that's not possible and editing the javascript is the way to go... I'm all for it.

Thanks.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pobqcoo/)

HTML

```
<div id="mainWrapper">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">AAA</a>
        <ul class="drop">
            <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAAAA.1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">AAA.1-1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">AAA.2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">AAA.2-1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">BBB</a>
        <ul class="drop">
            <li><a href="#">BBBBBBBBBB.1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">BBB.1-1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">BBB.2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">BBB.2-1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">CCC</a>
        <ul class="drop">
            <li><a href="#">CCCCCCCCCC.1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">CCC.1-1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">CCC.2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">CCC.2-1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">CCCCC.3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">CCC.3-1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">CCC.4</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">CCC.4-1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">CCC.5</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">CCC.5-1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC.6</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">CCC.6-1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#mainWrapper{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;
}

body{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;
}

ul#menu {
    list-style: none;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;
}

ul#menu a {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

ul#menu>li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 15px;
    display: table;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;
}

ul#menu>li ul.drop ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;
}

ul#menu>li ul li {
    list-style:none;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;
}

ul#menu>li ul.drop {
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 80px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    display: none;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;
}

ul#menu>li ul.drop li ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 220px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: green;
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('ul#menu li').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).children('.drop').size() > 0) {
            $("ul.drop").slideUp();
            $("ul.drop").find('ul').hide();
        } else {
            }
     $(this).children('ul').delay(20).slideToggle(600);
    });
});
$('ul').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just modified some selectors and now its working as you want it to work.

```
$(function(){
    $('ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul li a').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).parent().children('.drop').size() > 0) {
            $("ul.drop").slideUp();
            $("ul.drop").find('ul').hide();
        } else {
            }
     $(this).parent().children('ul').delay(20).slideToggle(600);
    });
});
$('ul').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pobqcoo/4/)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to satisfy the requirements by only modifying CSS rules.
How about this solution?:

```
ul#menu>li ul li {
    list-style:none;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;

    border: 1px solid black !important;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pobqcoo/5/)

This modified rules can limit the width of list items to adjust themselves to the width of inner text, I think. However, this is an ugly hack so I recommend modifying JavaScript.

Comment: That's because this is not an actual `float` usage. We should use `float` to direct the element flow order. This trick could affect the other elements neighbouring it. I recommend you'd make sure it doesn't affect the layout. :)

Answer (score 0):

To highlight the A element on the second menu you could add a css like this:

```
ul#menu>li ul.drop > li > a{
    background: gray;
}
```

and you can see that the element A don't have a width 100%

and if you want to have the width at 100%:

```
ul#menu>li ul.drop > li > a{
    background: gray;
    display: block; /* add this line */

}
```

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure you understood the problem... the issue is not the background color... it's clickable area.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have the whole li-tag as an onclick-reciever.
If you want only the text to be clickable you have to chose only the a-tags

```
$(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).closest('li').children('.drop').size() > 0) {
            $("ul.drop").slideUp();
            $("ul.drop").find('ul').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).closest('li').siblings('li').find('ul').hide();         
            }
     $(this).closest('li').children('ul')
     .delay(20).slideToggle(600);
    });
});
$('ul').on('click', function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
```

Try this fiddle. It should work as you expect.
    http://jsfiddle.net/lacrioque/84rmsgxc/

Comment: Are you sure that's the right fiddle? It behaves just like the one I posted. It changes nothing.